# How to reuse a variable without initializing a new one in for loop in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, initialization

I was writing a function in java which counts the number of characters after white spaces in a string. This problem might sound trivial to some of you.

```
public int countAfterSpaces(final String a){
   int position = 0; // escapes leading whitespaces
   while(position<a.length() && a.charAt(position)==' ') position++;
```

Now I want to reuse this variable (position) in a for loop without creating a new one (i) in the initialization statement. Currently I am doing this.

```
   int count = 0;
   for (int i=position; i<a.length; i++) count++;
   return count;
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `while` loop instead of `for`?

Comment: Though a loop isn't completely necessary in this case.

Comment: Yes, my question was a little different than this, I just made it a little simpler. I was basically trying to solve the atoi function. 
This required that I calculate the number of white spaces before the occurrence of any numeric character.

Comment: Java doesn't give you rewards points or anything for using the smallest number of variables.  It doesn't make your code more efficient, either.  It's best not to worry about things like that and worry about more important things, such as whether your code works and whether people who read it can understand it.  Or, in this case, whether you really need to use a loop.

Comment: Advice taken. It just reduces code clutter.

Comment: Ehhhhhhh.  A large majority of developers, I'd say, prefer to use new variables, so you're never unclear about what a particular variable means.  If a variable has two different roles you can get confused about which one is which.

Comment: "It just reduces code clutter" -- no, it doesn't.  Especially if the new variable is a loop index, because no additional code is needed to declare it.  If you start having too many variables so that it looks like clutter, it's time to break your method down into multiple methods.

Comment: Thanks for the professional advice @LouisWasserman

Comment: Thanks for the professional advice @ajb. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to declare a new variable:

```
for (; position<a.length; position++) count++;
```

You can leave any field of the for loop blank.

Or better yet, why not:

```
count = a.length - position;
```

Comment: Great. That seems to work. I will AC this after 10 minutes.